# How can I use lex and yacc to find my token?

Tags: c++, yacc, lex

I have a lex & yacc code to parse my file, but when executing it shows lex can't find my token.
As below:
[lex]:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "testinfoy.tab.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int yyline=1;
%}
%%
IDDQ { return IDDQ; }
ABC  { return ABC; }
\{   { return LBrace; }
\}   { return RBrace; }
[0-9]+ { return NUMBER; }
%%
void yyerror(const char *s) {
printf("Test.information %s at line %d, unexpected token %s\n",s,yyline,yytext);
exit(-1);
}
int yywrap()
{
    return 1;
}
```

[yacc]:

```
%token IDDQ LBrace RBrace ABC NUMBER
%%
IDDQItem :IDDQ LBrace RBrace  
| IDDQ LBrace ABCDef RBrace
;
ABCDef   :ABC LBrace NUMBER RBrace
{ cout << "---ABC---" << endl; }
;
```

My input file:  IDDQ { ABC  { 100 } }
It always show: Test.information syntax error at line 1, unexpected token ABC

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does your input file containing intervening whitespace between all the individual tokens? If so, which part of your lex/yacc grammar you think will handle them?

Comment: Please, don't post fixes of question in comment but [edit] the question itself.

Comment: A common reason for mysterious errors like this is that the token numbers produced by the lexer aren't the same as the token numbers expected by the parser. That csn happen if an old header file is used to compile the lexer, or if an old version of the lexer is being linked. Bison has a very useful tracing feature which can produce lots of good debugging information. See the "Debugging Your Parser" section of the Bison manual.